# How to add One2many relation in header-details invoice mod in odoo 12 properly?

Tags: python, odoo, one-to-many, odoo-view, odoo-12

i trying to build header-details relation for invoice module, but i don't really get how odoo 12 work for one2many relation, i have module named ms_produk, and my database name is "ms_produk_ms_produk", ms_produk module work as product master, which is CRUD product list, and i want the module to choose product when creating an invoice

here is what i do, i create a model that looked like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesorderSalesorder(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorder.salesorder'

    no_faktur = fields.Char(String='No Faktur', required=True)
    kd_dealer = fields.Char(String='Kode Dealer', required=True)
    nm_dealer = fields.Char(String='Nama Dealer', required=True)
    tanggal_faktur = fields.Datetime(string='Tgl Faktur', default=fields.Datetime.now())
    nm_sales = fields.Selection(
        [('bruno', 'Bruno'),('layla','Layla'),('vexana','Vexana')]
        ,string='Choose Seller')
    keterangan = fields.Html(string='Keterangan')
    kd_sales = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Kode Sales')
    details = fields.One2many('ms_produk_ms_produk','no_faktur','No Faktur')
```

but when the details written like this, it give me error like "Internal Server Error" the server won't start, then i changed it to :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesorderSalesorder(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorder.salesorder'

    no_faktur = fields.Char(String='No Faktur', required=True)
    kd_dealer = fields.Char(String='Kode Dealer', required=True)
    nm_dealer = fields.Char(String='Nama Dealer', required=True)
    tanggal_faktur = fields.Datetime(string='Tgl Faktur', default=fields.Datetime.now())
            nm_sales = fields.Selection(
        [('bruno', 'Bruno'),('layla','Layla'),('vexana','Vexana')]
        ,string='Choose Seller')
        ,string='Pilih Sales')
    keterangan = fields.Html(string='Keterangan')
    kd_sales = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Kode Sales')
    details = fields.One2many('salesorder.salesorder','no_faktur','No Faktur')
```

this works but wrong, it load the salesorder it self, what i want is, it appear product list, and i pick the product name and add it to the invoice details.

and here is my views, i named it salesorder_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="salesorder_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">SalesOrders</field>
            <field name="res_model">salesorder.salesorder</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create SalesOrders
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="salesorder_menu" name="SalesOrder"/>
        <menuitem id="Salesorder_neworder_menu" 
                parent="salesorder_menu" 
                name="New Order"
                action="salesorder_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

how to do that properly?

Comment: I think it is working for you details_ids = fields.One2many('ms.produk.ms.produk','no_faktur','No Faktur')

Comment: yea it's working, what i missed is i have link them with fields.Many2One in ms_produk model, but the result is not what i think lol, but yea it's worked haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While define One2many field you need to give the relation to table which you need to load, Please refer this [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields) to know about One2many fields.

By using form view you can design view of your model.

Comment: sure it's worked now man, i need to add Many2One relation in my ms_produk model, then it's working but the result is not what i imagine at, it show full CRUD module, i will start a new question for that issue, thanks for your help man, will accept this as answer